# What is the purpose of cURL?

Tags: php, http, curl

What is the purpose of cURL in PHP?

There are many different ways to open many different types of files. Why is cURL so commonly used?

Comment: sometimes, functionality is just made incase someone needs it. purpose may vary, depending on how it is used.

Comment: Have you ever tried to send a custom HTTP header with `file_get_contents`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there aren't as many ways of doing more complicated stuff like POSTing data and storing the cookies for another session.

Comment: +1 this is the best reason to use cURL. file_get_contents is *marginally* slower depending on what cURL options you're comparing it to, but the big reason to use it is that you can actually get the server to behave in almost any way that a normal browser client can (store cookies - and therefore maintain sessions -, submit _POST data, specify the browser agent, etc) and it can be optimized much more carefully depending on the specific task at hand.

Comment: FYI: `file_get_contents` can use cUrl transparently if enabled for the HTTP wrapper. However the wrapper has not that many options and you might be using the commandline tool, too, so that's a plus, too.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the many other reasons stated, based on benchmarks I have seen and my own experience, cURL is about 2x faster than using file_get_contents(); on a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Well for one its been around for a long time, and has become a standard of sorts. It builds and compiles across many platforms

> including Solaris, NetBSD, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Darwin, HPUX, IRIX, AIX,
>   Tru64, Linux, UnixWare, HURD, Windows, Symbian, Amiga, OS/2, BeOS, Mac
>   OS X, Ultrix, QNX, OpenVMS, RISC OS, Novell NetWare, DOS and more.

[Wikipedia Curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)

Answer (score 1):

A large number of code injection vulnerabilities reported in PHP-based web applications are caused by the combination of enabling allow_url_fopen and bad input filtering while using file_get_contents() and also CURL allows you to easily handle authentication. This is useful since some APIs use HTTP authentication etc ...

Answer (score -3):

CURL is a complex tool useful in many situations.
There is no real need for a "purpose", someone finds it useful and adapts to PHP :)